# ORA-24344: success with compilation error 103/9 PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers, rowtype

I am trying to create a trigger which will insert the record with some more data but my trigger creation is throwing compilation error

`[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
103/9   PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
16/9    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors`

Below is my trigger code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger insert_into_out_customer
before insert
on out_customer
for each row

DECLARE
v_username out_customer.created_by%TYPE;
newRow out_customer%ROWTYPE;
cId out_customer.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE;

begin

SELECT user INTO v_username
FROM dual;

:new.created_by := v_username;
:new.updated_by := v_username;
cId := :new.CUSTOMER_ID;


    SELECT  
    SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID  ,
    CUSTOMER_TYPE   ,
    CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE   ,
    FIRST_NAME  ,
    MIDDLE_NAME ,
    LAST_NAME   ,
    DOB ,
    PASSPORT_NUMBER ,
    GREEN_CARD_HOLDER   ,
    GREEN_CARD_NUMBER   ,
    TIN ,
    PRIMARY_ADDR_LINE_1 ,
    PRIMARY_ADDR_LINE_2 ,
    PRIMARY_ADDR_CITY   ,
    PRIMARY_ADDR_STATE  ,
    PRIMARY_ADDR_POSTAL_CODE    ,
    PRIMARY_ADDR_COUNTRY    ,
    PRIMARY_ADDR_PHONE_COUNTRY_CD   ,
    PRIMARY_ADDR_PHONE_NUMBER   ,
    PRIMARY_EMAIL   ,
    SECONDARY_ADDR_LINE_1   ,
    SECONDARY_ADDR_LINE_2   ,
    SECONDARY_ADDR_CITY ,
    SECONDARY_ADDR_STATE    ,
    SECONDARY_ADDR_POSTAL_CODE  ,
    SECONDARY_ADDR_COUNTRY  ,
    SECONDARY_ADDR_PHONE_CNTRY_CD   ,
    SECONDARY_ADDR_PHONE_NUMBER ,
    SECONDARY_EMAIL ,
    CITIZENSHIP ,
    COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN   ,
    NATIONALITY_1   ,
    NATIONALITY_2   ,
    BANK_STAFF_ID   ,
    SELF_CERTIFICATION_RESPONSE ,
    SELF_CERTIFICATION_REASON   ,
    SELF_CERTIFICATION_TIMESTAMP    ,
    'EDIT_FLAG' ,
    POA_EXISTS  ,
    POA_FIRST_NAME  ,
    POA_LAST_NAME   ,
    POA_DOB ,
    POA_ADDR_LINE_1 ,
    POA_ADDR_LINE_2 ,
    POA_CITY    ,
    POA_STATE   ,
    POA_POSTAL_CODE ,
    POA_COUNTRY ,
    POA_COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN   ,
    POA_PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE  ,
    POA_PHONE_NUMBER    ,
    BENEFICIARY_BANK_ADDRESS_LINE1  ,
    BENEFICIARY_BANK_ADDRESS_LINE2  ,
    BENEFICIARY_BANK_CITY   ,
    BENEFICIARY_BANK_POSTAL_CODE    ,
    BENEFICIARY_BANK_COUNTRY    ,
    BENEFICIARY_BANK_IFSC_CODE  ,
    'ACCOUNT_NUMBER'    ,
    'ACCOUNT_NAME'    ,
    'ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE'    ,
    'BASE_CURRENCY '   ,
   ' ACCOUNT_BALANCE_BASE_CURRENCY'    ,
   ' ACCOUNT_BALANCE_US_CURRENCY'    ,
    'GROSS_WITHDRAWALS'    ,
   ' GROSS_PROCEEDS'    ,
    'GROSS_DIVIDENDS'    ,
    'GROSS_INTERESTS'   ,
    'OTHER_INCOME'    ,
    sysdate
    POA_ID  ,
    STANDING_INSTRUCTION_ID ,
    BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT_ID  ,
    BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER  ,
    BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME    ,
    BENEFICIARY_BANK_NAME   ,
    STANDING_INSTRUCTION_START_DT   ,
    STANDING_INSTRUCTION_END_DATE   ,
    STANDING_INS_AMOUNT ,
    STANDING_INSTRC_FREQUENCY   ,
    :new.FATCA_REASON   ,
    :new.fatca_flag ,
    SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER.CREATED_BY   ,
    SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER.CREATED_DT   ,
    SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER.UPDATED_BY   ,
    SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER.UPDATED_DT   
    into newRow
    FROM SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER
    LEFT JOIN SAS_FATCA_ATTORNEY  ON SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = SAS_FATCA_ATTORNEY.CUSTOMER_ID
    LEFT JOIN SAS_FATCA_STANDING_INSTRUCTION ON SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = SAS_FATCA_STANDING_INSTRUCTION.CUSTOMER_ID
    where SAS_FATCA_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID= cId and rownum<2;


    :new.CUSTOMER_TYPE :=    newRow.CUSTOMER_TYPE ;
    :new.CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE :=    newRow.CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE ;
    :new.FIRST_NAME :=    newRow.FIRST_NAME ;
    :new.MIDDLE_NAME :=    newRow.MIDDLE_NAME ;
    :new.LAST_NAME :=    newRow.LAST_NAME ;
    :new.DOB :=    newRow.DOB ;
    :new.PASSPORT_NUMBER :=    newRow.PASSPORT_NUMBER ;
    :new.GREEN_CARD_HOLDER :=    newRow.GREEN_CARD_HOLDER ;
    :new.GREEN_CARD_NUMBER :=    newRow.GREEN_CARD_NUMBER ;
    :new.TIN :=    newRow.TIN ;
    :new.PRIMARY_ADDR_LINE_1 :=    newRow.PRIMARY_ADDR_LINE_1 ;
    :new.PRIMARY_ADDR_LINE_2 :=    newRow.PRIMARY_ADDR_LINE_2 ;
    :new.PRIMARY_ADDR_CITY :=    newRow.PRIMARY_ADDR_CITY ;
    :new.PRIMARY_ADDR_STATE :=    newRow.PRIMARY_ADDR_STATE ;
    :new.PRIMARY_ADDR_POSTAL_CODE :=    newRow.PRIMARY_ADDR_POSTAL_CODE ;
    :new.PRIMARY_ADDR_COUNTRY :=    newRow.PRIMARY_ADDR_COUNTRY ;
    :new.PRIMARY_ADDR_PHONE_COUNTRY_CD :=    newRow.PRIMARY_ADDR_PHONE_COUNTRY_CD ;
    :new.PRIMARY_ADDR_PHONE_NUMBER :=    newRow.PRIMARY_ADDR_PHONE_NUMBER ;
    :new.PRIMARY_EMAIL :=    newRow.PRIMARY_EMAIL ;
    :new.SECONDARY_ADDR_LINE_1 :=    newRow.SECONDARY_ADDR_LINE_1 ;
    :new.SECONDARY_ADDR_LINE_2 :=    newRow.SECONDARY_ADDR_LINE_2 ;
    :new.SECONDARY_ADDR_CITY :=    newRow.SECONDARY_ADDR_CITY ;
    :new.SECONDARY_ADDR_STATE :=    newRow.SECONDARY_ADDR_STATE ;
    :new.SECONDARY_ADDR_POSTAL_CODE :=    newRow.SECONDARY_ADDR_POSTAL_CODE ;
    :new.SECONDARY_ADDR_COUNTRY :=    newRow.SECONDARY_ADDR_COUNTRY ;
    :new.SECONDARY_ADDR_PHONE_CNTRY_CD :=    newRow.SECONDARY_ADDR_PHONE_CNTRY_CD ;
    :new.SECONDARY_ADDR_PHONE_NUMBER :=    newRow.SECONDARY_ADDR_PHONE_NUMBER ;
    :new.SECONDARY_EMAIL :=    newRow.SECONDARY_EMAIL ;
    :new.CITIZENSHIP :=    newRow.CITIZENSHIP ;
    :new.COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN :=    newRow.COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN ;
    :new.NATIONALITY_1 :=    newRow.NATIONALITY_1 ;
    :new.NATIONALITY_2 :=    newRow.NATIONALITY_2 ;
    :new.BANK_STAFF_ID :=    newRow.BANK_STAFF_ID ;
    :new.SELF_CERTIFICATION_RESPONSE :=    newRow.SELF_CERTIFICATION_RESPONSE ;
    :new.SELF_CERTIFICATION_REASON :=    newRow.SELF_CERTIFICATION_REASON ;
    :new.SELF_CERTIFICATION_TIMESTAMP :=    newRow.SELF_CERTIFICATION_TIMESTAMP ;
    :new.POA_EXISTS :=    newRow.POA_EXISTS ;
    :new.POA_FIRST_NAME :=    newRow.POA_FIRST_NAME ;
    :new.POA_LAST_NAME :=    newRow.POA_LAST_NAME ;
    :new.POA_DOB :=    newRow.POA_DOB ;
    :new.POA_ADDR_LINE_1 :=    newRow.POA_ADDR_LINE_1 ;
    :new.POA_ADDR_LINE_2 :=    newRow.POA_ADDR_LINE_2 ;
    :new.POA_CITY :=    newRow.POA_CITY ;
    :new.POA_STATE :=    newRow.POA_STATE ;
    :new.POA_POSTAL_CODE :=    newRow.POA_POSTAL_CODE ;
    :new.POA_COUNTRY :=    newRow.POA_COUNTRY ;
    :new.POA_COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN :=    newRow.POA_COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN ;
    :new.POA_PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE :=    newRow.POA_PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE ;
    :new.POA_PHONE_NUMBER :=    newRow.POA_PHONE_NUMBER ;
    :new.BENEFICIARY_BANK_ADDRESS_LINE1 :=    newRow.BENEFICIARY_BANK_ADDRESS_LINE1 ;
    :new.BENEFICIARY_BANK_ADDRESS_LINE2 :=    newRow.BENEFICIARY_BANK_ADDRESS_LINE2 ;
    :new.BENEFICIARY_BANK_CITY :=    newRow.BENEFICIARY_BANK_CITY ;
    :new.BENEFICIARY_BANK_POSTAL_CODE :=    newRow.BENEFICIARY_BANK_POSTAL_CODE ;
    :new.BENEFICIARY_BANK_COUNTRY :=    newRow.BENEFICIARY_BANK_COUNTRY ;
    :new.BENEFICIARY_BANK_IFSC_CODE    :=    newRow.BENEFICIARY_BANK_IFSC_CODE;

    commit;

end;
```

EDIT 1: below Query is working fine which means out_customer has all the columns

```
SELECT  CUSTOMER_ID    ,
CUSTOMER_TYPE    ,
CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE    ,
FIRST_NAME    ,
MIDDLE_NAME    ,
LAST_NAME    ,
DOB    ,
PASSPORT_NUMBER    ,
GREEN_CARD_HOLDER    ,
GREEN_CARD_NUMBER    ,
TIN    ,
PRIMARY_ADDR_LINE_1    ,
PRIMARY_ADDR_LINE_2    ,
PRIMARY_ADDR_CITY    ,
PRIMARY_ADDR_STATE    ,
PRIMARY_ADDR_POSTAL_CODE    ,
PRIMARY_ADDR_COUNTRY    , 
PRIMARY_ADDR_PHONE_COUNTRY_CD    ,
PRIMARY_ADDR_PHONE_NUMBER    ,
PRIMARY_EMAIL    ,
SECONDARY_ADDR_LINE_1    ,
SECONDARY_ADDR_LINE_2    ,
SECONDARY_ADDR_CITY    ,
SECONDARY_ADDR_STATE    ,
SECONDARY_ADDR_POSTAL_CODE    ,
SECONDARY_ADDR_COUNTRY    ,
SECONDARY_ADDR_PHONE_CNTRY_CD    ,
SECONDARY_ADDR_PHONE_NUMBER    ,
SECONDARY_EMAIL    ,
CITIZENSHIP    ,
COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN    ,
NATIONALITY_1    ,
NATIONALITY_2    ,
BANK_STAFF_ID    ,
SELF_CERTIFICATION_RESPONSE    ,
SELF_CERTIFICATION_REASON    ,
SELF_CERTIFICATION_TIMESTAMP    ,
EDIT_FLAG    ,
POA_EXISTS    ,
POA_FIRST_NAME    ,
POA_LAST_NAME    ,
POA_DOB    ,
POA_ADDR_LINE_1    ,
POA_ADDR_LINE_2    ,
POA_CITY    ,
POA_STATE    ,
POA_POSTAL_CODE    ,
POA_COUNTRY    ,
POA_COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN    ,
POA_PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE    ,
POA_PHONE_NUMBER    ,
BENEFICIARY_BANK_ADDRESS_LINE1    ,
BENEFICIARY_BANK_ADDRESS_LINE2    ,
BENEFICIARY_BANK_CITY    ,
BENEFICIARY_BANK_POSTAL_CODE    ,
BENEFICIARY_BANK_COUNTRY    ,
BENEFICIARY_BANK_IFSC_CODE    ,
ACCOUNT_NUMBER    ,
ACCOUNT_NAME    ,
ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE    ,
BASE_CURRENCY    ,
ACCOUNT_BALANCE_BASE_CURRENCY    ,
ACCOUNT_BALANCE_US_CURRENCY    ,
GROSS_WITHDRAWALS    ,
GROSS_PROCEEDS    ,
GROSS_DIVIDENDS    ,
GROSS_INTERESTS    ,
OTHER_INCOME    ,
BALANCE_DATE    ,
POA_ID    ,
STANDING_INSTRUCTION_ID    ,
BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT_ID    ,
BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER    ,
BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME    ,
BENEFICIARY_BANK_NAME    ,
STANDING_INSTRUCTION_START_DT    ,
STANDING_INSTRUCTION_END_DATE    ,
STANDING_INS_AMOUNT    ,
STANDING_INSTRC_FREQUENCY    ,
FATCA_REASON    ,
FATCA_FLAG    ,
CREATED_BY    ,
CREATED_DT    ,
UPDATED_BY    ,
UPDATED_DT    
from out_customer
```

I am not sure if this error is because of I am using %ROWTYPE variable to store query result. Please help me. And also if this is because of %ROWTYPE then what else I can use in place of %ROWTYPE

Comment: What is the point of this trigger?  You appear to be replacing all the values of an insert with a set of existing values.  That appears odd, to say the least.

Comment: @APC this trigger is appending all the information in out_customer on the basis of customer_id .....

Comment: I have selected all these columns from the table definition of out_customer. I mean I haven't written them one by one so there is no scope of error in terms of number of columns mismatch....

Comment: @APC Please look into the EDIT part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusingly in this case the error is because your select's projection has too few columns, not too many:

```
create table t42 (col1 number, col2 number);

declare
  x t42%rowtype;
begin
  select 1 into x from dual;
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
```

If you had too many columns in your select then you'd get `ORA-00947: not enough values`. Presumably this is based on the rowtype variable having too many columns compared to the select, rather than the other way round as you might expect.

In your case you are missing a comma. At the moment `POA_ID` is an alias for the `sysdate`, not a separate column. So this:

```
    'OTHER_INCOME'    ,
    sysdate
    POA_ID  ,
```

should be:

```
    'OTHER_INCOME'    ,
    sysdate,
    POA_ID  ,
```

Incidentally, this two-step process of selecting everything including values you already know into a rowtype variable, and then individually copy some of those values into the :new pseudorow columns, seems unnecessarily complicated, and may break if the table structure changes or the columns are not in exactly the order you expect. (Which can happen moving between environments; though it may be a sign you're doing some wrong).

Why not directly set the fixed values:

```
:new.created_by := user;
:new.updated_by := user;
:new.some_column := sysdate;
:new.some_column := 'EDIT FLAG';
...
```

and then only select the values you really have to get from other tables directly into a list of :new variables?

You also cannot commit inside a trigger.

Comment: thanks Alex, that was the problem ....
Also I understood that I should select values in separate variables to avoid future problems

Comment: DECLARE
CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE1 OUT_ENTITY.CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE%TYPE;

above code is throwing some error 
'[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
7/35    PLS-00302: component 'CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE' must be declared'

what could be the reason?  CUSTOMER_SUB_TYPE is a valid column name in out_customer

Comment: @NagendraYadav - what is `out_entity`? That isn't the table name you've been using. But `:new.customer_sub_type` is already that data type - why is using an intermediate variable better?

Comment: got the problem... it's not the table I want to use